# How do I get the RawUrl minus QueryString for a canonical link href?

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo

I'm trying to add a canonical link to the head of my masterpage in the following format (basically removing any querystring parameters):

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.domain.com/friendly-url/" />
```

Say somebody visited the page via the following URL, how would I remove the querystring from the url so I can create the canonical link above?

```
http://www.domain.com/friendly-url/?source=google
```

I've tried using Request.RawUrl but this returns the querystring as well as the friendly url. The whole point of the canonical link is to show our preferred version of the page to be indexed and this, in our case, is the URL minus anything in the querystring. The friendly URL makes this one complicated as I think it limits me to using Request.RawUrl, unless anybody can tell me different?

Comment: I think you want the [`Uri.AbsolutePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: The problem with AbsolutePath is that it will return the absolute file name like "friendly-name.aspx" instead of the friendly URL "friendly-name/". :(

Answer (score 0):

Take your `Uri` class and remove the query string from it:

```
Uri uri = HttpContext.Request.Url;
string friendlyUrl = uri.OriginalString.Remove(uri.OriginalString.IndexOf(uri.Query));
```